# Pass additional information to Azure Active Directory authentication flow

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

I am trying to secure my web api using azure active directory.

I have the following code to setup the web api:

```
public void BuildConfiguration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var HttpConfiguration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();

    HttpConfiguration.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    HttpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
                $"api/{{controller}}/{{action}}/{{id}}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    var authenticationProvider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = AuthenticationOnValidateIdentity
    };

    var options = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = "https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/yyy"
        },
        Tenant = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
        Provider = authenticationProvider
    };

    appBuilder.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(options);
    appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(HttpConfiguration);

    HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized();
}
```

Now, the code to perform the validation looks like this:

```
private async Task AuthenticationOnValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
{
    context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("apikey", xx)); // <- what to put here instead of xx?
}
```

The client requests a token using this piece of code:

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;

try
{
    result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://xx.onmicrosoft.com/yyy",  clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always), UserIdentifier.AnyUser);
}
catch (AdalException ex)
{
        ...
}
```

How can I pass additional info like an apikey (string) to the AAD validator so I can access the apikey in 'AuthenticationOnValidateIdentity'?

I tried the `extraQueryParameters` parameter like his:

```
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/yyy",  
             clientId, 
             redirectUri, 
             new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always),
             UserIdentifier.AnyUser, "apikey=test");
```

but since I cannot get these values anywhere in `AuthenticationOnValidateIdentity` I wonder if that is the way to go.

So, the question remains: How can I pass aditional information to Azure Active Directory authentication flow?

Comment: Can you try by specifying `state=test` instead of `apikey=test`. Looking at the protocol documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code, the state is always returned as is back to the application. However I could not figure out how you would get this information back in result.

Comment: @GauravMantri thing is, I do not know how to get to `state` in `AuthenticationOnValidateIdentity`. It does not show up anywhere while inspecting the context properties. At least I cannot find it..